# How do you have 2+ Function Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter

button=Button(window1,text="Create",command=Store_SQLite)

how do you put 2 functions into a tkinter button

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can put two functions to be triggered in a tkinter button; however, you could use a helper function that executes several other functions:

```
def handle_button_command():
    Store_SQLite()
    do_also_that()

def Store_SQLite():
    pass

def do_also_that():
    pass

button = Button(window1, text="Create", command=handle_button_command)
```

Comment: Possibly use a `lambda` for this?

Comment: Possibly - I find the helper more readable though - matter of taste.

Comment: @Coal_: functions are nearly always better than using `lambda`.

Answer (score -2):

You could also go like:

```
Button(command=lambda : [some_function(), some_other_function(), some_another_function()])
```

be mindful that their order do matter. I'd also rather use a handle function like in [Reblochon Masque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468697/7032856) though.

Comment: I think this would be a terrible solution. The right solution is to create a proper function, and call that function from a button. That function can then call as many other functions as it wants. Trying to crowd a bunch of code into a `lambda` creates code that is hard to understand, hard to debug, and hard to maintain.